# Python Web Scraping - Navigating to next page link and obtaining data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to navigate to links and extracting data (the data is a href download link),this data should be added to a new field besides the previous fields of the first page (from where i got the links),but i am struggling how to do that

Firstable,i've created a parse and extracted all the links of the first page and added it to a field named "Links",this links are redirecting to a page that contains a download Button,so i need the real link of the download button,so what i did here is to create a for loop with the previous links and executing the function yield response.follow but it didn't go well.

```
import scrapy
class thirdallo(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "thirdallo"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.alloschool.com/course/alriadhiat-alaol-ibtdaii',

]

def parse(self, response):

        yield {
          'path': response.css('ol.breadcrumb li a::text').extract(),
          'links': response.css('#top .default .er').xpath('@href').extract() 

        }

        hrefs=response.css('#top .default .er').xpath('@href').extract()
        for i in hrefs:
            yield response.follow(i, callback=self.parse,meta={'finalLink' :response.css('a.btn.btn-primary').xpath('@href)').extract() })
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `@href` you are trying to scrape out, it seems that you have some `.rar` links, that can't be parsed with the designated function.

Find my code below, with `requests` and `lxml` libraries:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml import html
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> resp = s.get('https://www.alloschool.com/course/alriadhiat-alaol-ibtdaii')
>>> doc = html.fromstring(resp.text)
>>> doc.xpath("//*[@id='top']//*//*[@class='default']//*//*[@class='er']/@href")
['https://www.alloschool.com/assets/documents/course-342/jthathat-alftra-1-aldora-1.rar', 'https://www.alloschool.com/assets/documents/course-342/jthathat-alftra-2-aldora-1.rar', 'https://www.alloschool.com/assets/documents/course-342/jthathat-alftra-3-aldora-2.rar', 'https://www.alloschool.com/assets/documents/course-342/jdadat-alftra-4-aldora-2.rar', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/44905', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43081', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43082', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43083', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43084', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43085', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43086', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43087', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43088', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43080', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43089', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43090', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43091', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43092', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43093', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43094', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43095', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43096', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43097', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43098', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43099', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43100', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43101', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43102', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43103', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43104', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43105', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43106', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43107', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43108', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43109', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43110', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43111', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43112', 'https://www.alloschool.com/element/43113']
```

In your code, try this:

```py
for i in hrefs:
    if '.rar' not in i:
        yield response.follow(i, callback=self.parse,meta={'finalLink' :response.css('a.btn.btn-primary').xpath('@href)').extract() })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,i've tried what you suggested to me,but i still don't get the field "Finallink" besides the previous fields (path and links)